# Is it possible to insert a new record in database table using jquery and mysql?

Tags: jquery, mysql

i've attend the interview for a job, they asked me one question like how do you insert a new record to the DB using only jquery and mysql? I answered to use jquery ajax, but they don't accept, they said we want to use only jquery and mysql and not any other. I've searched in google and didn't get possible solutions. Can you help me?

Comment: which company? give details plz.

Comment: If they really want to do this, feel happy for failing to this question. Maybe the answer would have been here "It's not possible unless you're a dirty dude"

Comment: You should have said: "I don't know, enlighten me".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**JavaScript/jQuery can not connect directly to the database And that is good for many reasons**

You need to make an Ajax call to the server to send the data that you want to be placed into the database. Youe server side code in the backed would do the connection to the mysql server.

Answer (score 4):

Only jQuery and MySQL - no.

JavaScript runs within a browser, and can do only what the browser allows.

Comment: "JavaScript runs within a browser" JavaScript can run in more environments :)

Comment: Yes, I meant it in the context of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I *completely* agree with the "you can't" answer. This may have been the case in the traditional configuration of a web application, however the interviewer may have been trying to test your reasoning on how to think outside the box.

There's no reason why you can't expose your database with a RESTful interface and accept calls directly from your browser using JQuery (using a direct AJAX call).

Alternatively, [DBSlayer](http://code.nytimes.com/projects/dbslayer) apparently provides a means of sending JSON requests to MySQL for processing.

In defense of @Champ's answer, s/he is correct from the point of view that *some form of server code* has to execute, so it's just a question of whether this is inherently supported by MySQL, or can be made to work using some form of MySQL plug-in or extension.